Call to undefined function add_action() with remote code
I built a Wordpress plugin using WAMP on my local sever, it's working fine. When I move it to a hosted Wordpress site, I use the Visual Studio SFTP sync extension to sync local PHP code to the WP instance. Once I do this, all the WP functions show up as "Call to undefined function" in the Visual Studio Code IDE. For example:
register_activation_hook()
get_user_meta()
add_shortcode()
add_action()


